# How to access a nested Dictionary<> objects in a foreach loop

Tags: c#, dictionary, foreach, nested

I have a nested Dictionary structure like this:

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> dict;
```

I'm trying to access the elements using two foreach loops but the compiler won't let me use the following as the loop variable for my inner loop:

```
Dictionary<string, string>
```

This is what I have:

```
foreach (string key in dict.Keys) {
    foreach (Dictionary<string, string> innerDict in dict[key]) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

The compiler says:

```
Cannot convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string,string>'
 to 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,string>'
```

I can use KeyValuePair<string,string> in the inner loop, but I would like to access the dictionary object itself as a whole (so that I can do something like this: if (dict.ContainsKey(innerDict)) { ... })

Answer (score 5):

The minimum code change to fix it is like this (but see the correct approach in the next code snippet in this answer):

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> dict;

foreach (string key in dict.Keys)
{
    foreach (var innerDict in dict[key].Select(k => k.Value))
    {
    }
}
```

Your problem was that when you enumerate over a dictionary, you get a sequence of Key/Value pairs. In your case, the Value was the inner dictionary, and it is *that* which you needed.

I'm using the Linq "Select()" operation to convert each key/value pair into just the value part, i.e. the dictionary which is the value in the key/value pair.

However, that's a long-winded and inefficient way to go about getting each inner dictionary along with its key. Here's how it should be done:

```
foreach (var item in dict)
{
    string key = item.Key;
    Dictionary<string, string> innerDict = item.Value;

    // Do something with key and innerDict.
}
```

I'm assuming that you are trying to visit each inner dictionary in turn while knowning that inner dictionary's key in the outer dictionary.

Note that I only copied the values from `item.Key` and `item.Value` into local variables to illustrate their types. You could just use `item.Key` and `item.Value` directly, of course.

If you really only want the inner dictionaries themselves (and you don't need the key for each inner dictionary), you can just do it like so (as Nuffin suggested):

```
foreach (var innerDict in dict.Values)
{
    // Use inner dictionary
}
```

Comment: You _do_ realize that a dictionary has a `Values` property, which provides direct access to the stored values, right?

Comment: @Nuffin I think he wants to use the outer dictionary key along with the inner dictionary, so I suggested the second approach. For the first, I was just corrected the syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

That's because the value of the `string` key is not a list. Change the declaration of the `Dictionary` to `Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<string, string>>> dict;` if that's what you want.

Or you could just grab the dictionary inside the first `foreach` loop like this:

```
Dictionary<string, string> val = dict[key];
```

and use it from there. But either way, you're trying to iterate against something that's not enumerable.

I think you may have the `Dictionary` defined like you want -you just don't need an inner loop.

Comment: @Ted, sorry, I saw a `&lt;` character in it when I viewed the question.

Comment: @user2455816, sorry, I saw a `&lt;` character in it when I viewed the question.

Comment: @Renan, sorry, I saw a `&lt;` character in it when I viewed the question.

Answer (score 1):

You could just keep it short by using:

```
foreach (Dictionary<string, string> d in dict.Values) {
}
```

It works, no complaints from the compiler.

Also notice that your code doesn't work because in that context, `dict[key]` is **not** a collection of dictionaries, but a single dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are misunderstanding the underlying Dictionary structure.

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>
```

The above results in a parent containing a single dictionary object.  When you attempt to use `foreach` over this object the compiler does not know what to do.  It might be easier to understand if you use the following code

```
Dictionary<string,string> dictionaryObject;
foreach (string item in dictionaryObject)
{ }
```

The above will also result in the same error.

You can resolve your issue by iterating over the keys or values of the dictionary object, for example,

```
foreach (string  key in dict.Keys)
{
    foreach (string innerKey in dict[key].Keys)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(dict[key][innerKey]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will still have the dictionary to reference just like you wish, even when you use the KVP.  Try this:

```
foreach (var outerKVP in dict {
    foreach (var innerKVP in dict[outerKVP.Key]) {
        var theString = dict[outerKVP.Key][innerKVP.Key];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (Dictionary<string, string> innerDict in dict[key]) {
        // ...
    }
```

This fails because `dict[key]` is a `Dictionary<string,string>`, so enumerating it with foreach will yield elements of type `KeyValuePair<string,string>`.

If you want to access the inner dictionary, just do so and drop the foreach loop.

```
Dictionary<string, string> innerDict = dict[key];
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be not so hard:

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> dict = new Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,string>>();

foreach (var kvp in dict)
{
    var innerDict = kvp.Value;

    foreach (var innerKvp in innerDict)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(kvp.Key + " " + innerKvp.Key + " " + innerKvp.Value);
    }
}
```